# How to split a float into two variables? (c++)

Tags: visual-c++

I can't figure out how to take the total number of hours and split it into regular hours and overtime hours.

What I would like to achieve is to: add a module that splits the number of hours worked into regular hours and overtime hours. This module must have one ‘in’ parameter and two ‘out’ parameters.

What I could come up with was:

```
if (total_hours >= 0 || total_hours <= 40) {
    reg_hours = total_hours;
}

if (total_hours >= 41 || total_hours <= 60) {
    ovt_hours = (total_hours - 40);
}
```

total_hours is my input. And reg_hours and ovt_hours are my outputs. If I put in 35.6 for total_hours, it'll compile and give me -4.40. It does fine with an input of 40 or higher, but when it comes to anything less than that it always produces a negative ovt_hours value. I'm really confused on how to stop it from giving me a negative number. I've been searching everywhere to find a solution, but I couldn't find anything that could help me understand what I am doing wrong. It would help me greatly if anyone could explain this in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Your OR (`||`) should be AND (`&&`)...

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an even larger negative value

Comment: Most likely, `reg_hours` and `ovt_hours` are uninitialized, initially containing random garbage. With code as written, both conditions are always true, and you are assigning `ovt_hours = (total_hours - 40)` even when `total_hours` is less than 40 - hence the small negative number. When you change from `||` to `&&`, you sometimes don't assign at all, and then you see the initial garbage value, which may very well be a large negative number.

Answer (score 1):

You can work up to 40 regular hours...

```
int reg_hours = max(total_hours, 40);
```

If you've worked more than 40 hours, then any extra hours are overtime hours...

```
int ovt_hours = 0;
if (total_hours > 40) {
    ovt_hours = total_hours - 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing you should understand:
Using "if" statement with another "if" statement (without "else if" or "else") would definitely make your compiler go to both "if" statements (assuming the conditions are true).

Also, you should notice that in your code there is a logic mistake:

1. "if (total_hours >= 0 || total_hours <= 40)"
2. "if (total_hours >= 41 || total_hours <= 60)"

When you input "total_hours=35.6", the compiler with go into both if statements. Why? Because 35.6 is >= 0 and <= 40 (1st if statement) and 35.6 is <= 60 (2nd if statement).

Therefore you MUST use "else if" for your 2nd if statement.

Another thing is that, you might need to consider to use "&&" instead of "||" since you are checking a range between 2 values. Using "||" means you are only checking a range lower/higher than a value.